# chmod exclusions

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ssh, chmod

I know I should assign a group and then set an umask so that groups writable permissions persist but for whatever reason I can't do this. I need to chmod recursively a directory except one sub folder (web10), would the following work?

```
cd /var/www/clients/
find . -type f -not -path "*web10*" -exec chmod 777 '{}' \;
```

Comment: This question is better suited for the [UNIX & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) StackExchange site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude files or directories, you use `-prune`

```
find /var/www/clients/ -name web10 -type d -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0640
```

You should also use `xargs` where possible. With `-exec` you call the command once for every file found, whereas `xargs` collects as many files as possible and calls the command once for N files, resulting in a more efficient execution and better performance.

Comment: `sudo: unable to execute /bin/chmod: Argument list too long` any way to deal with that?

Comment: @Ascherer I don't see, how sudo fits in here. That depends on the concrete command line. It is best to ask a new question with the complete example.

Comment: running the chmod at the end as sudo. Found too many files it looks like

Comment: @Ascherer `xargs` should prevent this. I just saw, that I missed the `-0` argument to xargs. Please retry.